# Using BS, I cannot "find" the ID of info, when I know it exists

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am a new user to Beautiful Soup and am trying to create a baby application that retrieves the view count from a YouTube url.

So, I looked at the BS docs and I saw that you could retrieve items by their id. So I attempted to retrieve the info id - but whenever I attempt to do this, it comes out as "None", so it must not be finding the id.

[image: HTML ID INFO]

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUPvE5yv72I'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

divisions = soup.findAll("div")

print(divisions[0])

info = soup.find(id="info")
print(info)
```

Comment: The page is loaded with javascript. BS/requests cannot run JS by itself. They can only process whatever you get in the page source (Ctrl + U). Try using Selenium or Youtube's own API

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to search for `meta itemprop="interactionCount"` tag, but this value can be often not exact. Best way is using the official YouTube API:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUPvE5yv72I'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('meta[itemprop="interactionCount"][content]')['content'])
```

Prints:

```
165011
```